# Retrieving tcp header using boost::asio::ip::tcp socket

Tags: sockets, tcp, boost-asio

I developed a TCP backend using boost asio and now I need to access the whole TCP packet (header + body). It is possible using TCP sockets?

Comment: You need raw sockets (`SOCK_RAW`) to access TCP header (and IP header) and payload (it is not called body - don't confuse this with HTTP).

Comment: Not that most platforms restrict access to RAW sockets to admin users only.